# Build a new flat list from a mix of part items and part spans

Tags: list-manipulation, concatenation

I want to modify a list of  table row by adding an extra column. For that I [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the data with a pure function that evluate the new column value from exisiting one and reconstruct a new list from that and the initial [`Part`s](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) of the list:

```
b = 5000
data = {{1, 45000., 27500., "Inverted"}, 
        {2, 22500., 18333.3, ""}, 
        {3, 15000., 13750., "Inverted"}, 
        {4, 11250., 11000., ""}, 
        {5, 9000., 9166.67, "Inverted"}, 
        {6, 7500., 7857.14, ""}, 
        {7, 6428.57, 6875., "Inverted"}}

{#[[1;;3]], #[[1]]> 2b, #[[4]]} & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{{1,45000.,27500.},False,Inverted},
>    {{2,22500.,18333.3},False,},
>    {{3,15000.,13750.},False,Inverted},
>    {{4,11250.,11000.},False,},
>    {{5,9000.,9166.67},False,Inverted},
>    {{6,7500.,7857.14},False,},
>    {{7,6428.57,6875.},False,Inverted}}
> ```

The problem is `#[[1;;3]]` return a list--so I end-up with nested list instead of flat records.

As a workarround, I [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) each record:

```
    Flatten[{#[[1;;3]], #[[1]]> 2b, #[[4]]}] & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{1,45000.,27500.,False,Inverted},
>    {2,22500.,18333.3,False,},
>    {3,15000.,13750.,False,Inverted},
>    {4,11250.,11000.,False,},
>    {5,9000.,9166.67,False,Inverted},
>    {6,7500.,7857.14,False,},
>    {7,6428.57,6875.,False,Inverted}}
> ```

```
Flatten[{#[[1;;3]], #[[1]]> 2b, #[[4]]}] & /@ data
```

It works *in that particular* case. But it is not entirely satisfactory since, if the initial record would already contain list items, they would have been flattened too.

If there a more generic solution to build a list from items and list spans?

Comment: Thanks @Marco. I didn't have yet encountered the `:>` notation. I need to take a look at that!

Comment: Sylvain, yes, both `@@@` (i.e. Apply at level 1) and [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) are worth looking into!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{## & @@ #[[1 ;; 3]], #[[1]] > 2 b, #[[4]]} & /@ data
```

or

```
{Sequence @@ #[[1 ;; 3]], #[[1]] > 2 b, #[[4]]} & /@ data
```

> {{1, 45000., 27500., False, "Inverted"},
>   {2, 22500., 18333.3, False, 
>     ""},
>    {3, 15000., 13750., False, "Inverted"},
>   {4, 11250., 11000., 
>     False, ""},
>    {5, 9000., 9166.67, False, "Inverted"},
>    {6, 7500., 
>     7857.14, False, ""},
>    {7, 6428.57, 6875., False, "Inverted"}}

Comment: Thnaks, @kglr, you gave me [an idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211058/68791) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Two options presented themselves to me, using `Apply` or using replacements:

```
{#1, #2, #3, #1 > 2 b, #4} & @@@ data
data /. {x_, y_, z_, p_} :> {x, y, z, x > 2 b, p}
```

Both reproduce your results.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative: 
`Join[#[[1 ;; 3]], {#[[1]] > 2 b, #[[4]]}] & /@ data`

Answer (score 0):

While posting my question, the system suggested me the [concatenation](/questions/tagged/concatenation), which in its turn lead me to the [`Catenate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html) function. It works at the expense of few additional brackets:

```
Catenate[{#[[1;;3]], {#[[1]]> 2b}, {#[[4]]}}] & /@ data
(*                   ^          ^  ^      ^
```

> ```
> {{1,45000.,27500.,False,Inverted},{2,22500.,18333.3,False,},{3,15000.,13750.,False,Inverted},{4,11250.,11000.,False,},{5,9000.,9166.67,False,Inverted},{6,7500.,7857.14,False,},{7,6428.57,6875.,False,Inverted}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat a variation around the [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) symbol that was suggeste by @kglr in [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211055/68791):

```
{#[[1;;3]] /. List -> Sequence, #[[1]]> 2b, #[[4]]} & /@ data
```